# Not the whole data received in a socket C# WP8

Tags: c#, sockets, buffer

The code below is perfectly working when i receive "small" data.
But when i try to receive a big data , it always cut.
The data that i received isn't whole

```
static ManualResetEvent _clientDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        const int TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 500000000;

        const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

 public string Receive_msg()
        {
            string response = "Operation Timeout";

            if (_socket != null)
            {
                SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = _socket.RemoteEndPoint;

                socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);


                socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                    {
                        response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                        response = response.Trim('\0');
                        Debug.WriteLine(response);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                    }

                    _clientDone.Set();
                });

                _clientDone.Reset();

                _socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);

                _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
            }
            else
            {
                response = "Socket is not initialized";
            }
            return response;
        }
```

I tried to increase the value of the TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS and the size of my MAX_BUFFER_SIZE , but nothing change. I need to be able to get a bigger data.
And i must use this way, i can't use WebClient or HttpWebRequest...

Comment: As far as i know you should make your big data chunk into small bytes and send first a package with the lenght of all data you are trying to send. and after that you should make n request to get small sizes of  the data and put it all together when it's finished

Comment: What makes you think you'll get a complete, valid UTF-8-encoded string in a single go? You're calling `Receive` once, but that doesn't mean you'll necessarily receive the whole data within the socket. Bear in mind that TCP sockets are effectively streams of data, so you should treat them that way... don't assume you're done reading until you see the stream has been closed. If you're trying to exchange multiple messages on a single connection, you'll probably want to length-prefix each message.

Comment: i tried several things put didn't work...i still can't get the whole data

Comment: Unfortunately, you've painted yourself into a corner. You will need a streaming UTF8 decoder for this to work. There is no other way to tell whether or not you have the entire message. You are paying the costs of poor protocol design -- the message layer was implemented without planning.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't receive all the data you want, just call your receive function again.

Also, and this very important, before you implement anything on top of TCP, *document* the protocol you're using unless you're implementing a protocol that's already documented. It may be helpful to read the protocol documentation for some protocol layered on top of TCP such as SMTP, IRC, HTTP, or the like.

Comment: i tried several things put didn't work...i still can't get the whole data

Comment: What's the problem? What happens when you call the receive function again?

Comment: I got much more than before ! (with the loop i have edited with the good one) But still not all data , and i this time really no idea why

Comment: How do you know you didn't get all the data exactly? Can you be precise about what goes wrong? How many bytes do you send? How many do you receive? What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: I'm using a terminal who send data(i can't touch the code to know how many bytes are sent) . The terminal work perfectly the data is correctly sent.
One of my problems is that i can't count how many bytes i got/received.  I just know the data (string) and i can see my result. And it doesn't match. My result is smaller than my data even with my loop

Comment: @Fly_federer Log the number of bytes you received each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't count on getting all your data in a single socket read.  You have to put in a loop that will continue to receive data until there is no more data to receive.

How, then, do you tell when you have received all your data?  You have a couple of options: you can send a delimiter byte that will only appear at the end of the message; if you see that as the last byte received you are done.  Otherwise, you can send the length of the message at the start of the message (this is what HTTP does, btw).  Or you can have the sender close the socket when the message is complete, and just keep reading until there is an EOF condition on the socket.

Comment: Actually, HTTP supports all three methods. You can send the length (Content-Length), you can use a delimiter (chunked encoding) or you can use the closing of the connection (if there's no length header and chunked encoding is not used).

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the receive call will only read the minimum length between the receiving packet size and the buffer you use for reading. I suspect the data you send to be too large and getting split by the system into smaller packets (called fragmentation).

I would prefix anything you send with an integer (4 bytes, the size of the data to come), read it on the receiving side and read bytes from the socket as long as you haven't received the length you sent as a header.

Edit: Since you can use TcpClient, I would recommend using this and the `.GetStream()`. Tell me if i'm wrong, but this program should send and receive strings only (according to your code). Here's what I would do:

```
public async Task<string> ReceiveString()
{
    NetworkStream netStream = _client.GetStream(); //Using _client instead of _socket
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(netStream);
    string result = await streamReader.ReadLine(); //Reading the stream until we find a newline
    return result;
}
```

And you would use it like so:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    string message = await ReceiveString(); //This is the fully async way, the "MyMethod" signature should be "async void" too in order to use "await"

    string message = ReceiveString().Result; //This is a blocking call, waits for everything to be received before proceding
}
```

Note: This code works if you end all your messages with a newline character. It also only applies if you only want to transfer strings (as mentioned above, I assumed).

Comment: i tried several things put didn't work...i still can't get the whole data

Comment: I would try using async-await and Socket.ReceiveAsync() instead of events in a SocketAsyncEventArgs

Comment: Can you show me the way ? 
With what i'm reading my problem can be solve with loop on the data that send to me....But i still not success...If ever you have any idea .

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong about the ReceiveAsync method call. I thought the signature was different and returned Task<int>. Have you tried with [BeginReceive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: I have already tried... Do you think with my actually way, is impossible that i success ?

Comment: One thing I want to know: is there any way you could use TcpClient? i know you can't use WebClient or HTTPWebRequest but...

Comment: I'm developping an app who will download his informations through a terminal (Linux..) . As you said i can't use webClient or HTPP. But i can use TcpClient

Comment: Sorry for two comments, to build my receive function i used this https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Oh, i don't understand how to use it in my case..looks hard and i think i must use socket. But anyway thanks  a lot !.

Comment: You just have to call 'ReceiveString().Resul't, that gives you the received string. TcpClient is a subclass of Socket too.

Comment: I didn't notice to you but my App is for Windows Phone 8, and NetworkStream isn't on the platform

Comment: I see, you should really put that in the question then!